# How to stop Dataproc Job from airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

From Airflow we can submit dataproc jobs via DataprocSubmitJobOperator.

We can stop dataproc jobs in development environment but not in Production environnment via GCP Console.

Is there any way, we can kill dataproc jobs directly via Airflow, if dataproc job id is provided as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there is no operator for this action but `DataprocHook` has [`cancel_job`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/3f6d5eef427f3ea33d0cd342143983f54226bf05/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/dataproc.py#L770) function so you can create a custom operator :

```
class MyDataprocCancelJobOperator(BaseOperator):
    """ Starts a job cancellation request."""

    template_fields: Sequence[str] = ("region", "project_id", "impersonation_chain")

    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        job_id: str,
        project_id: str,
        region: Optional[str] = None,
        retry: Union[Retry, _MethodDefault] = DEFAULT,
        timeout: Optional[float] = None,
        metadata: Sequence[Tuple[str, str]] = (),
        gcp_conn_id: str = "google_cloud_default",
        impersonation_chain: Optional[Union[str, Sequence[str]]] = None,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.job_id = job_id
        self.project_id = project_id
        self.region = region
        self.retry = retry
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.metadata = metadata
        self.gcp_conn_id = gcp_conn_id
        self.impersonation_chain = impersonation_chain

    def execute(self, context: 'Context'):
        hook = DataprocHook(gcp_conn_id=self.gcp_conn_id, impersonation_chain=self.impersonation_chain)
        job = hook.cancel_job(
            job_id=self.job_id,
            project_id=self.project_id,
            region=self.region,
            retry=self.retry,
            timeout=self.timeout,
            metadata=self.metadata,
        )
        return job
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Airflow  Dataproc doesn't include an operator to cancel job. See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html. Maybe you can raise a feature request in the airflow community.